# How can I get my game to respond to an arrow input using C# in Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game in Unity using 3D and C#. Currently I am controlling the block with letters on the keyboard using `if (Input.GetKey("d"))` but would like to use arrow keys instead. I have looked at other questions on Stack Overflow explaining how to respond to space bar inputs but not how to respond to arrow key inputs.

Comment: Thanks. That helps but I still needed to know how to add the arrow keys.

Comment: There is also `Input.GetAxis()`. Unity provides default "Horizontal" and "Vertical" axes you can access through this method and it automatically registers both arrow keys and WASD for up/down/left/right movement. You can also customize it which is pretty neat

Comment: Both answers on the dup-target include information for getting arrow keys. That's why its a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```cs
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) 
{
    // Left arrow is being held down
}
```

Here's a list of all KeyCodes you can use: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html

To get a single click, use `Input.GetKeyDown`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html